# Using coefficients (slope and intercept) from one data frame to calculate a list of values from a second data frame

Tags: r, arrays, dataframe, dplyr

I have a list of lengths (n=30) for several species, let's call them A1, A2, A3, A4, A5:

```
A1<-(sample(x = 0:100, size  = 30, replace=TRUE))
A2<-(sample(x = 0:100, size  = 30, replace=TRUE))
A3<-(sample(x = 0:100, size  = 30, replace=TRUE))
A4<-(sample(x = 0:100, size  = 30, replace=TRUE))
A5<-(sample(x = 0:100, size  = 30, replace=TRUE))

df<-data.frame(A1,A2,A3,A4,A5)
```

[image]

For each of these length for each species, I'd like to use a species-specific slope and intercept (y=mx+b) to calculate weight:

```
sample <- c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5")
intercept <- rnorm(5, mean = 10, sd = 1)
slope <- rnorm(5, mean = 10, sd = 1)
upper <- rnorm(5, mean = 10, sd = 1) + rnorm(5, mean = 0.01, sd = 1)
lower <- rnorm(5, mean = 10, sd = 1) + rnorm(5, mean = 0.01, sd = 1)

coef<-data.frame(sample, intercept, slope, upper, lower)
```

where upper and lower are 95% confidence intervals.

[image]

My question is, for each row of the column (df) per species (i.e. for each length value), how can I calculate  weight from the species-specific y = slope * x + intercept values in the coef dataframe?

I've tried making additional columns (eg A1.intercept, A1.slope, A1.upper, A1.lower) for each species and then repeating the same value from (coef) across rows, but 1) I can't get the code to work properly and 2) I have many species (A1 - A70) so the code is painfully long.

I've tried various grep options but I'm coming up blank. Any help very gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, you can first create the intercept matrix where you repeat the intercepts for the number of observations:

```
b = t(replicate(nrow(df),coef$slope[match(colnames(df),coef$sample)]))
```

Then, you multiply every row by the matching slope:

```
mx = sweep(df,2,coef$slope[match(colnames(df),coef$sample)],"*")
```

What you need is:

```
y = mx+b
```

You can also merge using dplyr (i guess not too bad since you don't have a lot):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% tibble::rownames_to_column("id")  %>% 
pivot_longer(-id,names_to="sample") %>% 
left_join(coef)  %>% 
mutate(y=intercept+value*slope)
```

Comment: The base R solution is incredibly elegant - thank you! But shouldn't it be `mx = sweep(df,2,coef$slope[match(colnames(df),coef$sample)],"*")` not `mx = sweep(df,2,coef$slope[match(colnames(df),coef$sample)],"/")` ?

Comment: oh yes.. sorry.. i use "/" too often. thank you for spotting my mistake

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1) # reproducible data set
A1<-(sample(x = 0:100, size  = 30, replace=TRUE))
A2<-(sample(x = 0:100, size  = 30, replace=TRUE))
A3<-(sample(x = 0:100, size  = 30, replace=TRUE))
A4<-(sample(x = 0:100, size  = 30, replace=TRUE))
A5<-(sample(x = 0:100, size  = 30, replace=TRUE))

df<-data.frame(A1,A2,A3,A4,A5)

sample <- c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5")
intercept <- rnorm(5, mean = 10, sd = 1)
slope <- rnorm(5, mean = 10, sd = 1)
upper <- rnorm(5, mean = 10, sd = 1) + rnorm(5, mean = 0.01, sd = 1)
lower <- rnorm(5, mean = 10, sd = 1) + rnorm(5, mean = 0.01, sd = 1)

coef <- data.frame(sample, intercept, slope, upper, lower)

If I have understood your question this may help you
df %>% 
tidyr::gather(sample,x) %>% # get df in long format
left_join(.,coef,"sample") %>% # join data
mutate(y = slope * x + intercept) # apply equation
```